# React Monaco Editor AutoComplete Bug

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I'm thinking of JSON editor as Monaco editor.
Make {} CTRL + SPACE BAR first, then enter Enter to wrap up the line.
If you continue with a specific auto-complete immediately, the first item of the auto-complete tooltip is not selected, and even if you enter the enter immediately, the auto-complete item is not selected.
I will attach the image.
How can I resolve this issue?

[image]